# Strange result of Javascript split in Ant

Tags: java, javascript, ant, split

Javascript´s `split` function behaves different while splitting a literal and splitting a string read from a file.

I have the following file with a character, a colon and a newline:

```
$ cat line
a:
$ od -a line
0000000   a   :  nl
0000003
```

And when I run the following build file:

```
<project name="project">
  <script language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[
      importClass(java.io.BufferedReader);
      importClass(java.io.File);
      importClass(java.io.FileReader);

      var literal = "a:";
      var readline = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("line"))).readLine();

      project.log("literal: '" + literal + "' -> " + literal.split(":").length);
      project.log("readline: '" + readline + "' -> " + readline.split(":").length);
    ]]>
  </script>
</project>
```

I get the following result:

```
$ ant -f split.xml
Buildfile: split.xml
literal: 'a:' -> 2
readline: 'a:' -> 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Splitting a literal returns 2 and splitting a string read from a file returns 1.

Can anybody explain what is going wrong here and how I can fix it?

I tested it with Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on July 18 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`literal` is a JavaScript string. `readline` is a Java string. The two differenct split methods behave differently. The Java documentation says *... Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.*

Comment: You are right. Java does the unthinkable. What a stupid API bug.